# Use JPublisher with jdk8

Tags: java, java-8, oracle10g

I have a program that executes a command [jpub](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/java.901/a90214/sampcode.htm) like this

```
executeCommand("jpub -u "+args[0]+"/"+args[1]+" -package="+args[3]+" -codegen=iso -url="+args[2]+" -plsqlpackage="+resultSetMain.getString(1)+" -dir "+args[4]+" -case=lower -plsqlfile="+resultSetMain.getString(1)+"_wrapper.sql,"+resultSetMain.getString(1)+"_wrapper_drop.sql -s "+resultSetMain.getString(1)+":"+resultSetMain.getString(1)+"_OUT -compile=false -omit_schema_names");
```

when `execCommand` is simply a private function that gets a runtime instance and executes the command :

```
Process pr = rt.exec(command);
```

I'm using maven to build my project.
when I run my program with eclipse Juno everything is fine, but when I want to migrate to the latest version of eclipse when I run `mvn clean install` i had this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/io/CharToByteConverter
```

I have tried to build a jar `converter` that contains this class and to add it to my project but this is not working

```
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>my-local-repo</id>
        <url>file://${basedir}/lib</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>ma.me</groupId>
        <artifactId>converter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
        </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reading the documentation of the JPublisher I have found a section that speaks about how to specify JVM through which JPublisher is invoked [doc](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/JJPUB/optinfil.htm#JJPUB24173).

We can use the `-vm=value` parameter where the value is the location of `JDK6`or 7, so you can run the command like this:

```
executeCommand("jpub -u "+args[0]+"/"+args[1]+" -package="+args[3]+" -codegen=iso -url="+args[2]+" -vm="+args[8]+" -plsqlpackage="+resultSetMain.getString(1)+" -dir "+args[4]+" -case=lower -plsqlfile="+resultSetMain.getString(1)+"_wrapper.sql,"+resultSetMain.getString(1)+"_wrapper_drop.sql -s "+resultSetMain.getString(1)+":"+resultSetMain.getString(1)+"_OUT -compile=false -omit_schema_names");
```

In our exemple `args[8]` contains the path of executable java 6 for exemple : `D:\Java\jdk6\bin\java`